# Scaling Kubernetes Deployment of Node.js Express Server Pods without Downtime

Tags: node.js, express, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

### Question

Is there a way to avoid any of the following errors when scaling Kubernetes Deployments of Node.js Express server Pods?

- Connection refused
- Timeout (60s)

### Background

I have a Node.js microservice that runs `server.close()` against all running servers when `SIGTERM` is received. This should stop new connections from coming in while wrapping up existing connections when a Pod is killed.

I have tested the functionality of `server.close()` locally and it behaves exactly as desired.

When scaling the corresponding Kubernetes Deployment up/down (in loop for tests), I find that my `curl` requests fail with `connection refused` and `timeout` most of the time. These requests are sent while the rollout is occurring.

There is always at least 1 Pod running at all times during the rollout. However, the failures happen even when multiple Pods are up.

I have a Readiness Probe implemented which hits the `/status` endpoint of the Server.

This is on GKE and the Pods are exposed through a LoadBalancer Service.

### Deployment Spec

All relevant parts of relevant Deployment spec.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  minReadySeconds: 5
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      containers:
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 2
          httpGet:
            path: /status
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 10
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

### Test Code

This is the Bash loop that fails. This excerpt shows the scale up/down logic tested.

Note that `checkController` is a function that `curl`s a LoadBalancer Service pointing to the Deployment being scaled up/down.

```
  for REPLICAS in 1 3 1 2; do
    kubectl scale deployment controller --replicas $REPLICAS
    checkController # <-- curl test
    kubectl rollout status deployment controller
  done
```

`kubectl get pods --watch` shows pods being deleted and created as you would expect based on the scaling loop. There is always at least 1 Pod ready.

Comment: Hello. Could you provide the `YAML` manifest of your `Deployment`? Have you configured the `RollingUpdate` inside of it? Also can you share the sample of code that would replicate the behavior you are experiencing?

Comment: @DawidKruk done, thanks

Comment: Hello. Sorry for such a late response. I tried to replicate the issue you are experiencing on a  `GKE` cluster but I was not able to. I ran the example nodejs server with options you provided. I simultaneously curled the LB (every 0.1s) and scaled the replicas many times and each and every time it worked. Could you share minimal reproducible example of your code (or an image with it) to reproduce it further? Which `GKE` version are you running?

Comment: Thanks very much for the info. I will try to recreate the issue in a simpler deployment situation - the one I am testing is relatively complex. Then I will post the details